# How to get the canvas.create_text() text value in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

```py
from tkinter import *

canvas = Canvas(width=500, height=100, bg="black")
typed_value = canvas.create_text(250, 50, text="5+7", font=("courier", 25, "bold"))

canvas.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

## i want to get the value of the text in the typed_value I have used get(1.0 End) and cget(1.0, End)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
txt = canvas.itemcget(typed_value, 'text')
```